# How to implement Weber contrast of an image in matlab/octave?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave, contrast

I would like to get per-pixel local contrast of an image, and I guess [Weber contrast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_%28vision%29) is a plausible formula for that. Question is, how to get it in matlab assuming we just use neighboring pixels (ex, 5x5) for Ib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate local contrast we need a luminance image, and local background luminance.

Assuming we already have a luminance image, the local background luminance for a particular pixel can be calculated by taking the average over all pixels in the local region.

We can collect a set of such local background regions (one per pixel in the original image) by repeatedly shifting the image by 0:(n-1) pixelsin both horizontal and vertical directions.

The following demo function illustrates the basic idea:

```
function weberContrastDemo

    imgWidthPixels            = 1024;
    imgHeightPixels           = 1024;
    localBackgroundSizePixels = 5; % square patch

    luminance     = randn( imgHeightPixels, imgWidthPixels );
    luminance( 496:528, 496:528 ) = 20;
    background    = localMeanFilter( luminance, localBackgroundSizePixels );
    weberContrast = ( luminance - background );% ./ background;

    imagesc( weberContrast );
    title( 'Weber Contrast' );
    colormap(gray);

end

function filteredImg = localMeanFilter( img, regionSizePixels )

    offsetImages  = getOffsetImages( img, regionSizePixels );
    filteredImg   = mean( offsetImages, 3 );

end

function buffer = getOffsetImages( img, regionSizePixels )
% GETOFFSETIMAGES

    imgSize      = size( img );
    imgHeight    = imgSize( 1 );
    imgWidth     = imgSize( 2 );

    minDelta     = 0;
    maxDelta     = (regionSizePixels-1);

    bufferWidth  = imgWidth  + maxDelta;
    bufferHeight = imgHeight + maxDelta;
    bufferDepth  = regionSizePixels .^ 2;
    bufferSize   = [ bufferHeight bufferWidth bufferDepth ];
    buffer       = zeros( bufferSize );

    iSample = 0;

    for deltaX = minDelta:maxDelta

        iStartX = 1        + deltaX;
        iEndX   = imgWidth + deltaX;
        idxX    = iStartX:iEndX;

        for deltaY = minDelta:maxDelta

            iSample = iSample + 1;

            iStartY = 1         + deltaY;
            iEndY   = imgHeight + deltaY;
            idxY    = iStartY:iEndY;

            buffer( idxY, idxX, iSample ) = img;

        end
    end

    iMin   = ceil(regionSizePixels/2);
    iMax   = iMin + (imgWidth-1);
    buffer = buffer( iMin:iMax, iMin:iMax, : );

end % GETOFFSETIMAGES
```

For a real psychophysical experiment we would want to convert parameters from radians or steradians to pixels, and would need to calibrate the display or image capture device so the luminance measure is accurate.